# Sorting String arrayList alphabetically after word that comes after \t [Java]

Tags: java, file, sorting, notepad

I have created a book library in notepad that looks like this :

```
    Author           | Name of the book | Availability? | Readers Code | Return Date

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    J. K. Rowling      Harry Potter       Yes             -              -
    Mark Sullivan      The Black Book     Yes             -              -
    Margaret Atwood    Rogue              Yes             -              -
```

And i need to sort this by name of the books alphabetically.
Words are separated by using \t.
How can i do that?

```
This is the code that adds new books :
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter("C:/Users/Name/Desktop/library.txt", true))) {


                    System.out.print("Enter authors name\t");
                    name = sc.nextLine();
                    name = sc.nextLine();
                    author[l] = name;

                    System.out.print("Enter books name\t");
                    name = sc.nextLine();
                    bookname[l] = name;

                    vaiBib[l] = "Yes";
                    BilNr[l] = "-";
                    AtgDat[l] = "-";

                    l++;

                    if ((author[l- 1] != null) && (bookname[l- 1] != null)) {
                        content = bookname[l- 1] + "\t\t" + author[l- 1] + "\t\t" + vaiBib[l- 1]
                                + "\t\t\t" + BilNr[l- 1] + "\t\t" + AtgDat[l- 1];
                        bw.write(content);
                        bw.newLine();

                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And with this code i make linked lists from lines that are in notepad :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Name/Desktop/library.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> Line2= new ArrayList<>();
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        Line2.add(line);
                    }
```

Comment: Can you help us out and edit your post by adding code?

Comment: this makes it much easier to answer. but **PLEASE POST MINIMAL NECESSARY CODE!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use Java 8:

```
Line2.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf('\t') + 1)));
```

In earlier Java versions you will need to write a `Comparator` class, you can find numerous examples and tutorials on the Internet. The basic idea of comparing the part of the string that comes after the first tab by taking `s.substring(s.indexOf('\t') + 1))` is still valid, you will just need to do it for each of the two strings you are comparing.